# What is an appropriate way to name an HTML table for future reference

Tags: html

I would like to create a new HTML table for specific holidays only if such a table hasn't been already created on an existing web page (using Python). What is the best way to name the HTML table when I am creating it for the first time so that all I need is to check the name to know if the table has been already created in the past? Is there any better way to do this?

For example, let's say, I am creating a table for the Christmas holidays (12/24 and 12/25). There is an existing page that has tables from the past holidays and I need to keep those old tables intact (so I can't just create a new page every time.) For the first time, I could generate hardcoded name like "christmasholidays2021" (since there are not too many holidays in the U.S.) and use it as a property like  so that I can check it if a table already exists next time? Is this an appropriate thing to do? Any better way to do this?

Comment: HTML is not a database. It is not intended for data-storage. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Maybe you can add an ID or Class in the <table> tag and name it like this: Christmas-Holidays-2021

Comment: @dram95, are there any specific reasons I should use ID or Class instead of Name as a property of <table> tag? Is that part of HTML guideline?

Comment: @Dai, I am not using it as data-storge. I will display the table on the page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.